# Magento categories listing using getCollection & addLevelFilter but exclude Default Root Category

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm using the following code to grab a collection and to filter on a level using addLevelFilter(2). This outputs all my categories at level 2 perfectly except it also pulls through the Default Root Category in my list. I want to exclude this from view but having looked through all the available methods, I see nothing that will help me remove/exclude certain levels or categories. I really want a full proof solution so if I were to choose say level 3 it would only show level three and not level 1,2,3. Does anyone have a suggestion to pull only a certain level/categories!!??

```
<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                    ->addLevelFilter(2)
                    ->addOrderField('name');
    foreach($categories as $category):
?>
    <div class="home-cats">
        <div class="product-image">
           <a href="<?php echo $category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="88" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any advice/feedback would be greatly appreciated. Cheers, Sahus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try

```
->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
```

this may work for you

Comment: Thanks @naresh-tank that did the trick. Do you know of any filter which might help with getting only the current child categories. I'm using the code above for the home page to get all main child categories of the root. But say I'm 3-4 levels deep into sub categories and on any particular category page I only want to retrieve it's Children!? Any idea how I might achieve that!?

Comment: if you want to all child category of perticular cater then you can use  $currenCat->getAllChildren().other wiseuse $currenCat->getChild()

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would I use the above $currentCat->getAllChildren() before or after ->getCollection(). Actually thinking about it would I use it in the foreach like so foreach($categories->getAllChildren() as $category)

Comment: getAllChildren() method give you all id as comma sepreted id so you have to expload first and use array as you wnat to use