# Magento - filter category by description

Tags: magento, categories

In magento, I need to pull all categories that have text "test-category-block" in the description.
I tried to add addFieldToFilter but doesn't work.
Is there an easy way to do it?

**Update:**

Just found another question, this might help me: [Magento categories listing using getCollection & addLevelFilter but exclude Default Root Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304240/magento-categories-listing-using-getcollection-addlevelfilter-but-exclude-defa)

**SOLVED:**

```
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array('gt' => 1))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('description', array('like' => '%category-search-filter%'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do this to filter on text within the description field:

```
 $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('description', array('like' => '%test-category-block%'))
```

If you don't use the `like` array param, then it will do only match on descriptions that *equal* the provided value, not that contain it.